# How to rspec ActionDispatch::ParamsParser::ParseError in Rails Api

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, rails-api

I am trying to write a failing spec for passing a invalid json when making a request to a rails api endpoint.

In a full rail api I would have used capybara and curl to make the actual request.

How do I pass a invalid json via a rspec request spec?

Comment: You can do a controller test in rspec.  https://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-rails/docs/controller-specs

Answer (score 2):

I ended up finding a solution to this, you need to use request specs, something along this lines:

```
require 'rails_helper'

RSpec.describe 'JSON formatting', :type => :request do
  context 'with bad json' do
    it 'returns 400 on bad json' do
      headers = {
          'ACCEPT' => 'application/json',
          'CONTENT_TYPE' => 'application/json'
      }
      post '/some/path', "{", headers

      expect(response.content_type).to eq("application/json")
    end
  end
end
```